# Live encryption and decryption of audio

Tags: hardware, encryption

So I am trying to mix my software skills with my electronics skills, and I want to try something a bit different. Basically: buy a walkie talkie, take it apart, remove the microphone and put a rasp pi or arduino between the mic and the cuircuits, encypting everything sound. On the corresponding device I will do the same, just soldered in before the speaker. It does not need to be mil-tec encryption, making it not comprehensable for anyone else would be sufficient.

I know there are a bunch of issues, but I think the biggest ones are:

1. I can't encrypt **everything** at once, so I need to encrypt a certain amount of bits, resulting in possible noise if it gets shifted due to unavoidable noise on  the channel, unless I put it to a very high pitch and only look out for that.
2. The encryption. I am not big with encryption, but wouldn't it be enough to take, let's say 512 raw bits and multiply them by a prime and playing it back faster to compensate the transmition taking longer?
3. The dencryption. How bad will noise be? If I say 'hello' and it comes out as 'chr - hello - chr' this is not a problem for us smart humans, but if the encrypted bits would be 01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 (Hello) and the first 0 gets lost, would it not shift everything and make it inaudible gibberish (10010000 11001010 11011000 11011000 1101111 which is ����o) or even break cause my bytes aren't 'full'? How do I combat this?

Or you summarise the problem as 'encrypting analog data and sending it on a device with a lot of noise'

I know this question might be considered a tad bit 'broad', but I could not find anything helpfull about live encryption and especially encrypting a live audio analog signal. I only found [this](http://jtxp.org/tech/hektor_en.htm) which is basically a big version of what i envisioned. Mine doesn't need to be that big/complicated, just not evesdroppable for people who might use the same legal and open radio frequencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this down:

Step 1: Convert the analog voice into digital.  Not a problem, there are hardware chips that do that.  If you're only concerned about low fidelity voice, your bandwidth requirements will be very small.

Step 2: Chop up the incoming data stream into blocks

Step 3: Encrypt each block using some standard algorithm.  Never invent your own!

Step 4: ((hard part here)) - convert each block back into audio tones and transmit

Step 5: receive the audio tones and convert back into each block of data

Step 6: decrypt the data

Step 7: send the data to your DAC (digital to analog converter chip) and then to a speaker.

---

If you replace steps 4 and 5 with "transmit over Ethernet", you've just invented Voice over IP (VoIP) with encryption (SSL?).  In short, very much a solved problem.

The hard part is going to be to essentially "[binhex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BinHex)" your data - take each byte and convert it into an audible tone of sufficient length that your receiver will recognize it.  This is also a solved problem - we used to call them "[acoustic modems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem)"

Your first step in research is to **ensure that what you're proposing is legal in your country**.  Public frequencies are often allocated by purpose, and transmitting data over an audio channel may not be permitted.  Please check.

As for your specific questions:

```
1. I can't encrypt **everything** at once...
```

Agreed.  You break it into blocks of perhaps 4k bytes and encrypt each block.  Experiment!

```
2. The encryption...
```

Never try to invent your own encryption scheme!  Just find an existing one and use it. Existing encryption algorithms have been tested and have known performance - an amateur may write something that soaks up a lot of processing time folding/spindling/mutilating the data only to come up with ciphertext that's easily crackable by a bright 6 year old.

```
3. ...How bad will the noise be?...
```

You're right to be concerned.  The usual approach is to send the data along with sufficient redundant data so that the recipient can at least detect if not actually rebuild missing data.  The lazy way to do this is to install a full TCP stack on both of your walkie-talkies and let the libraries take care of it for you.  I'm not sure if that's an option or not.  If not, this project just moved from "a cool hobby project that may or may not be legal" into "this is way too much work to invent something that's not as useful as my cell phone"

Comment: For the legality: I am using open frequencies to transmit data, that is legal. I and friends might want to play for example airsoft on a big field and communicate without being intercepted. I thought hey, if I can not even encrypt it but just convert sound into binary noise into sound, I would be very much set. If I send this at 30k hertz, noone will hear it.

I will just try to do this, and if it doesn't work it doesn't work, no problem there

Comment: You've skipped over one of the most challenging aspects: handling dropped bits and noisy data on the receiver. The typical encryption algorithms we are used to aren't going to cut it.  "If you replace steps 4 and 5 with "transmit over Ethernet", you've just invented Voice over IP (VoIP) with encryption (SSL?). In short, very much a solved problem" - this isn't relevant because a walkie talkie doesn't have resending abilities, plus ethernet is a very low noise transmission medium. Also, referencing modems is inappropriate, as ordinary modem are not capable of real time transmission of digitized

Comment: audio at all but the lousiest of sampling rates, and even then, modems over phone lines already have the benefit of significantly better fidelity than low power radio signals.

Answer (score 1):

You would most likely want to do something similar to this:

[image]
<sub>*[cryptomuseum.com](https://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/voice.htm)*</sub>

The input is the voice signal that you want to encrypt.  You would use the same Key and pseudo random number generator (PRNG) on both sides.  At the other end, just repeat the same process, and the exclusive or stage (XOR) will give you your original digitized waveform back.